# self-signatures using SHA1

Tags: cryptography, hash, digital-signature, pgp

[This page](https://help.riseup.net/en/security/message-security/openpgp/best-practices#self-signatures-should-not-use-sha1) says:

> self-signatures must not use SHA1
>
> You can check this by doing:
>
> ```
> gpg --export-options export-minimal --export <keyid> | gpg --list-packets |grep -A 2 signature|grep 'digest algo 2,'
> ```
>
> If you see any ‘digest algo 2’ results printed, then you have some self-signatures that are using SHA1, as digest algo 2 is SHA1. See the OpenPGP RFC 4880, section 9.4 for a table that maps hash algorithms to numbers.

I set up a key following best practice instructions (Debian's developer keysigning guidelines), but I get `digest algo 2` lines printed when I run this. What exactly does this mean, and what part of setting up the key affects this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does mean some part is signed using SHA1 as hashing algorithm. If you view the full output of `gpg --export-options export-minimal --export <keyid> | gpg --list-packets`, you may find which part.

Comment: I thought I'd followed all the "best practice instructions" for a secure key, but I apparently hadn't. Following the steps [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/48) to generate a new key resulted in one that passed all the tests from the site in my original question.